# Point to an element belong to HTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For example: This is my code

```
<script>
function changeMe()
{
    document.myform.mytable.mybutton.value = "Changed!";
}
</script>

<body>
    <form id = "myform" name = "myform">
        <table id = "mytable" name = "mytable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id = "mybutton" name = "mybutton" value="OK!" onclick="changeMe();"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

But it doesn't work. But when I change:

```
document.myform.mytable.mybutton.value = "Changed!";
```

into

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').value = "Changed!";
```

It works perfectly. Please tell me what wrong with my first code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id = "myform" name = "myform">
            <table id = "mytable" name = "mytable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id = "mybutton" name = "mybutton" value="OK!" onclick="changeMe(this.id);"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <script>
            function changeMe(elementId)
            {
                document.getElementById(elementId).value = "Changed!";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```